# What's the best way to play a .mp3 in iPhone App ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iphone sdk support for playing mp3 files over the network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275990/iphone-sdk-support-for-playing-mp3-files-over-the-network)

I need to play a .mp3 in my iPhone app. The .mp3 is on a server, and I just have the URL of it. It would be nice if it could be played in a UIWebView. In any case I want to stay in my app, and stream it.

Comment: Have a look at the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273197/i-want-to-play-mp3-files-on-my-server-with-avaudioplayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `MPMoviePlayerController`. Despite the name, it fully supports audio-only streaming.

Answer (score 0):

What omz said.

Btw, this is a very nice article which gives an overview of the history of iDevice media APIs:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/03/history-of-ios-media-apis-iphone-os-20.html

It will give you some idea of the options available.